# What's wrong with my cs50 vigenere code? I am close on the output

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I have spent hours on this and I am still stuck.  I am getting the following output when I do my check.  Do the errors have something to do with the way I am printing it out?

- :) vigenere.c exists
- :) vigenere.c compiles
- :( encrypts "a" as "a" using "a" as keyword
  \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: a\u0004ù\u001bÿ\n"
- :) encrypts "barfoo" as "caqgon" using "baz" as keyword
- :) encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword
- :) encrypts "BARFOO" as "CAQGON" using "BAZ" as keyword
- :( encrypts "world!$?" as "xoqmd!$?" using "baz" as keyword
  \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: xoqmd!$?í\b@\n"
- :( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "xoqmd, rby gflkp!" using "baz" as keyword
  \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: xoqmd, rby gflkp!^¿µÿ\n"
- :) handles lack of argv[1]
- :) handles argc > 2
- :) rejects "Hax0r2" as keyword

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define alpha_length 26

char secret(char character, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    //check that there are only two strings
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./vignere k\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //check that argv1 is alphabetical
    string code = argv[1];
    for (int t = 0; t < strlen(code); t++) {    
        if (!isalpha(code[t])) {
            printf("Alphabetical only!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //get string from user to encrypt
    printf("plaintext: ");
    string plaintext = get_string();

    //array created out of user inputted plain text
    char cypher[strlen(plaintext)];

    //j counts the number of alphabetical characters so that it resets based on argv length
    int j = 0; 
    //iterate over characters in array.  If they are alpha then apply the function secret
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++) {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i])) {
            int index = j % strlen(code);
            int code_index = toupper(code[index]) - 'A' ;
            cypher[i] = secret(plaintext[i], code_index);
            j = j + 1;
        } else {
            cypher[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cypher);

    return 0;
}  

char secret (char character, int key) {
    char shift;

    // if the character is upper case then start with uppercase A and shift based on the appropriate character from argv1
    if (isupper(character)) {
        shift = (int)character -'A';
        shift = shift + key;
        shift = (shift % alpha_length) + 'A';
    } else {
        // else start wit lower case a
        shift = (int)character - 'a'; 
        shift = shift + key;
        shift = (shift % alpha_length) + 'a';
    }
    return (char)shift;
}
```

Comment: 1) `char cypher[strlen(plaintext)];` --> `char cypher[strlen(plaintext)+1];` +1 for NUL charancter. `%s` of `printf` requires that the string be terminated with NUL characters.

Comment: So you also need to terminate that string after the encoding loop, before you pass it to `printf`, with `cypher[i] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- do not use the `string` typedef from `<cs50.h>`: it hides the nature of the object you are manipulating, a simple `char *` pointer which you should learn to master without fear.
- because type `char` can be signed by default and have a negative value for which `isalpha()` is undefined, you should cast the `char` arguments to these functions as `unsigned char`: `isalpha((unsigned char)code[t])`
- you intend for `cypher` to be a C string, so you must allocate an extra byte for the null terminator and store it there:

  ```
  char cypher[strlen(plaintext) + 1];
  ```
- cipher is spelled with an `i`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define alpha_length 26

char secret(char character, int key);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //check that there are only two strings
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./vignere k\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //check that argv1 is alphabetical
    char *code = argv[1];
    int code_len = strlen(code);
    for (int t = 0; t < code_len; t++) {    
        if (!isalpha((unsigned char)code[t])) {
            printf("Alphabetical only!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //get string from user to encrypt
    printf("plaintext: ");
    char *plaintext = get_string();
    int text_len = strlen(plaintext);

    //array created out of user inputted plain text
    char cipher[text_len + 1];

    //j counts the number of alphabetical characters so that it resets based on argv length
    int j = 0; 
    //iterate over characters in array.  If they are alpha then apply the function secret
    for (int i = 0; i < text_len; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)plaintext[i])) {
            int index = j % code_len;
            int code_index = toupper((unsigned char)code[index]) - 'A';
            cipher[i] = secret(plaintext[i], code_index);
            j = j + 1;
        } else {
            cipher[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
    }
    cipher[text_len] = '\0';
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);

    return 0;
}  

char secret (char character, int key) {
    int shift;

    // if the character is upper case then start with uppercase A and shift based on the appropriate character from argv1
    if (isupper((unsigned char)character)) {
        shift = (int)character - 'A';
        shift = shift + key;
        return 'A' + (shift % alpha_length);
    } else {
        // else start with lower case a
        shift = (int)character - 'a'; 
        shift = shift + key;
        return 'a' + (shift % alpha_length);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0, text_len =` ... `cipher[i] = '\0';`  --> `int i = 0; for (int text_len = ` ... `cipher[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: yes of course! thank you. I keep making this mistake, the scope of the `for` initial expression definitions bugs me.

Comment: `text_len`  undeclared now. :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I hope I finally got it right.  I could also use `printf("ciphertext: %.*s\n", text_len, cipher);` but with a lesser pedagogical value.

Comment: That @BLUEPIXY guy is a pretty *sharp cookie* and *tough critic*. If the comments subside -- you're in the clear `:)`

Comment: `char cipher[len + 1];` : `len` typo as `text_len`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: fixed. I should compile these toy programs and let the compiler help me avoid silly typos and scoping errors.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: yes indeed! If he does it without compiling, he has a very sharp eye.